# Laravel Notifications not responding to APP_URL changes

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

I am testing my password reset notification to see if it responds to changes in the APP_URL, unfortunately it does not.
It responds to changes in the APP_NAME env variable nonetheless.
I cleared my cache, I cleared my views, I ran php artisan optimize:clear and unfortunately nothing worked.

What is quite strange is that it responds to changes in the APP_NAME not the APP_URL ...

This is my env file

```
APP_NAME=WP
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:uqkPjWhwt7orbinLRlRN+BNn6BxbdIRHSV4dG4dw5S0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://example.com
```

This is the ResetPassword toMail() function which is unaltered

```
    public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    if (static::$toMailCallback) {
        return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $this->token);
    }

    if (static::$createUrlCallback) {
        $url = call_user_func(static::$createUrlCallback, $notifiable, $this->token);
    } else {
        $url = url(route('password.reset', [
            'token' => $this->token,
            'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset(),
        ], false));
    }

    //dd(env('APP_URL')); returns http://example.com
    // dd(config('app.url')); returns http://example.com
    // dd($url); returns http://127.0.0.1:8000/{token}?email!




    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Notification'))
        ->line(Lang::get('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
        ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), $url)
        ->line(Lang::get('This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.', ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')]))
        ->line(Lang::get('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
}
```

Comment: I use dd to see what the URL looks like in the ResetPasswod class which extends notification and, unfortunately, it shows the localhost not the one in the APP_URL. 
When I use dd to fetch the APP_URL variable it shows me the one I set. 
What could be the problem here?

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using? and did you stop the serving of the project and ran it again?

Comment: Laravel 8. and Yes I run the project again.
In the toMail method, dd(env('APP_URL')) and dd(config('app.url')) return the domain name.
But dd($url) uses the localhost ...

Comment: I think the issue is that it does not use my url (despite it being defined in the env file and config file) as the root for my routes

Comment: it would be helpful to put examples of your code as well as your env file, sometimes something you missed can be caught by fresh eyes

Comment: I put the code above ^ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queued notifications will use the APP_URL config value when building urls. However, non-queued notifications will use the HTTP request information when building urls.

The `ResetPassword` notification is not a queued notification, so it will use the url from the original HTTP request that triggered the notification. In this case, it looks like you're testing locally at http://127.0.0.1:8000, so that is the base url that will be used to build the password reset link.

If the notification was queued, then the notification would be sent using a queue worker that runs the console kernel. The console kernel builds a fake request, which sets the base url based on the APP_URL config value.

---

Note, there was a period of time where the ResetPassword notification specifically used `config('app.url')` in the notification to build the URL. This was introduced in 5.4.22, but later removed in 6.18.7. Since then, it has behaved like every other notification.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! Many many thanks really! :))

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`  after making changes to your .env file.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#configuration-caching

Comment: I did this and sadly it did not work as well...

In the toMail method in the reset password class that extends notification, dd(env('APP_URL')) and dd(config('app.url')) return the domain name.
But dd($url) uses the localhost ...